# ERP Framework to use in development?

Tags: frameworks, enterprise-library, erp

We are about to start developing an ERP for small companies, and the question is if there is some free framework for ERP that I can use? Is something done to accelerate the process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little unclear from your question what you're wanting. If you want to use existing open source ERP software and possibly extend it (subject to the terms of its license), there's a nice list at [List of ERP software packages on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ERP_software_packages).

If you're wanting a framework that will help you write a custom ERP package, I am not aware of any such software. I'd treat it like any other software project - gather requirements, then look for pieces that can be used off-the-shelf. Some examples:

- [O/RMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software)
- Logging frameworks like [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/) (ports exist for other languages)
- [IoC Container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Existing_frameworks) frameworks
- Pluggable architecture frameworks like [MEF](http://www.codeplex.com/MEF) (.NET-specific)

And so on. Don't go overboard; use only the pieces you need.

EDIT: Apparently at least one ERP framework exists: [WyattERP](http://wyatterp.com/). If you're comfortable with Tcl, it may be worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is: IntarS. Open Source, Universal Application, several working example ERP systems available.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Apache OFBiz](http://ofbiz.apache.org/) - an open source enterprise automation software project. Also, there is a [Wikipedia definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_OFBiz).

Answer (score 1):

Try [OpenERP](http://www.openerp.com). OpenERP (previously known as TinyERP) is an open source integrated enterprise resource planning (ERP) software manufactured by OpenERP s.a.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are okay with ASP.NET MVC C# you can have a look at the [ERP Core Framework](http://arinsyscorp.com/services-solutions/products/arinsys-core/) provided by [Arinsys](http://arinsyscorp.com/). You can download the [Nuget package here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Arinsys.Enterprise.Core/). It's built over ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 framework with ports to ASP.NET 4.5+